# In a SectionList how do i hide the section header of an empty section (data:[])

Tags: list, react-native, header, sectionheader, react-native-sectionlist

I'm using react-native's SectionList and can't hide the sectionheaders of  the empty sections of my dataset. I want to show only the section headers and the rows of the sections that are not empty.

Comment: You should mark @Andre Simon's answer as accepted

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is what I did:

```
<SectionList
   renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => (
      section.data.length > 0 ? this._renderHeader(section.title) : (null)
   )}
   ...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<SectionList>
    renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title, data } }) =>
            data.length > 0 && <Text>{title}</Text>
            }
    ...
</SectionList>
```